# Using eclipse RecordingCommand.doExecute with exception

Tags: java, exception, eclipse-emf, emf

I'm extending the class RecordingCommand from org.eclipse.emf.transaction.RecordingCommand;
and override method- protected void doExecute() in the method I there is possible error
so my question is how can i handle it?i.e.throw the exception

```
@Override
protected void doExecute()
{
```

Comment: no,I want to raise it up

Answer (score 0):

If the exception comes from inner calls, I would recommend:

```
protected void doExecute() {

   try {

    //do your logic

   } catch(Exception e) {
     throw e;
   }
```

Comment: but im overriding this method is it possible?

Comment: its not that simple since  im overriding this method and in the method interface there is not exception so the if some API will call to doExcute i think he face issue since the exception is not defined in tne interface

Comment: I have removed `throws` part since it is not declared in the interface. You need to `catch` the `Exception` in the method where you call `doExecute()`